# How to define \section to compile conditionally

Tags: sectioning, conditionals, sections-paragraphs

I would like to create a structural delimiter that behaves identically to `\section` but compiles conditionally.  In the MWE below I have labeled it `\draftsection`.  The content of this section should only compile if `\draftmodetrue`.  How should I define `\draftsection`?

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\newif\ifdraftmode
\draftmodefalse

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Apple}
        \lipsum{1-2}
    \section{Banana}
        \lipsum{2-3} % Always show this

    \draftsection{Cherry}
        %  if \draftmodefalse do not compile anything from here
        \lipsum{3-4} %(should not be shown, since \draftmodefalse)
        %  To here

         %% if \draftmodetrue, everything should compile identically to the case \draftsection were replaced by \section

    \section{Durian}
        \lipsum{4-5}  % Since this is not a draft section it should always be shown

\end{document}
```

I also know that I can create a conditional comment as in the code below:

```
\newif\ifdraftmode
\DeclareRobustCommand{\draftcomment}[1]{
\ifdraftmode
#1
\fi
}
```

I'm hoping that I can find a solution that (effectively) automatically places the end brace `}` of the `\draftcomment` above at the start of the next section.

That is I think I basically want

```
\draftcomment{\section {section content} }
```

Where {section content} is everything between Cherry and Durian.
The problem is that I don't know how to get latex figure out what `{section content}` is automatically.

How does LaTeX keep track of which content is in which section?
Clearly for equation numbering latex keeps track of which chapter the equation arises in.

I usually compile with lualatex, so I'm OK with solutions that require that, or not.

Comment: You can use the comment package. It provide a way to define environments that can be conditionally included or not.

Comment: This sounds promising, can you provide or link to an example.  Part of what I'm hoping is that the \end{environment} logic will be taken care of by the start of the next section.

Comment: Here is the [comment package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/comment/comment.pdf). But adding it in the section command will be complex. This is an *environment* that, as all envs, must be opened and closed... What about the first \section?   And what will close the last one? IMHO using an environment (that can have a section name as parameter) is more flexible. Maybe you would like to exclude subsections, or a bunch of paragraphs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could define `\draftsection` in the following way:

```
\long\def\draftsection#1#2\section{%
  \section{#1}% Print regular \section{<title>} for \draftsection{<title>}
  \ifdraftmode
    #2% Only print content between \draftsection and next \section if in draft mode
  \fi
  \section% Restore captured \section for next \section
}
```

Here's what it does:

- It prints `\section{<title>}` whenever you use `\draftsection{<title>}` (regardless of the state of `\ifdraftmode`;
- Content between `\draftsection{<title>}` and a subsequent `\section` is only printed if `\draftmodetrue`.
- It *requires* there to be an *explicit* `\section` following the `\draftsection{<title>}`. As such, you cannot have a `\draftsection{<title>}` as the last section within your document.
- The definition needs to be updated if you plan on using a `*` (starred, unnumbered) version, or need an optional argument (as in `\draftsection[<ToC entry>]{<title>}`).

Comment: Although if the draft section is the last section in the article, it will fail.

Comment: @DonHosek: True, as noted in the third bullet.

Comment: D'oh! That's what I get for reading the code and not the comments.